# React JS Ignore server side rendering

Tags: javascript, facebook, reactjs

I am working on an "Isomorphic" web application based on React, Redux, React Router, Nodejs etc...

In my case I doing server side rendering in order to enable search engines to crawl the web site and social networks to read the meta tags when sharing to them

I have this case where the rendering is actually different when a user is logged in (personalised) and when no user is logged in (server side rendering, is session-less)

The problem is that once a user is logged in the web client side rendering fails with:
`Invariant Violation: You're trying to render a component to the document using server rendering but the checksum was invalid. This usually means you rendered a different component type or props on the client from the one on the server, or your render() methods are impure. React cannot handle this case due to cross-browser quirks by rendering at the document root. You should look for environment dependent code in your components and ensure the props are the same client and server side:
 (client) operty-fb=2app_id">...
 (server) operty-fb=2app_id">...`

I guess my question, is there a way to tell react in some cases, don't do a checksum test and just re-render the entire DOM?

Comment: Your use case is not uncommon, but to get that error, something is likely wrong in your implementation. Can you share some code?

Comment: React can ignore checksum errors and will just re-render the DOM, *except* when rendering at the document root (because of the issues mentioned in the error).

Comment: Yep, that's exactly what I am doing, I am managing the entire document with React , anyway to overcome this?

Comment: I ended up, passing the state from the server to the client  
In my case it wasn't the best solution  
I wish I could have an option to flush the virtual DOM that created from the html react got from the html on first client render